# AWS Codecommit CICD to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, devops, cicd

I am using AWS CodeCommit for managing my repository and have an EC2 instance where the code is deployed.
Tried setting up CodePipeline - skipped Build Stage and it seems to work fine but it takes over 10-12 mins to complete. I see the majority of time is taken in the Source stage where I I believe it zips the code, uploads to S3 and then deploy downloads from S3 (which is another concern as this would mean higher S3 and network cost).

Would there be a more optimal way to setup a pipeline that would quickly deploy changes to a branch onto EC2 instance?

Thank you.

Tried to lookup documentation on CodePipeline but there is no much information

Comment: I guess you are using SAM templates to build the infrastructure. AWS in the backend would create CFN, zip it, deploy the configuration to S3 and create the infra. During the first run, it would take some time but the consecutive runs should be pretty fast

Comment: Not using any templates. Followed the documentation here to setup https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html. It takes 10 minutes on average for each commit

Answer (score 0):

In this case to avoid the time taken process at source stage. We can use the same configuration for the code pipeline by skipping build stage, but here we can configure Step 4 : beta page as shown in below figure:

[image: Setting up Elastic Beanstalk]

Once we start our pipeline, it will start to run automatically. First, it detects the sample code in source location, bundles up the files, and move to second stage that you defined. During this stage, it passes the code to Elastic Beanstalk, which contains the EC2 instance that will host our code. Elastic Beanstalk handles deploying the code to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot see a Beta option in my CodePipeline